# HP notebook has slow processing power

Tags: 14.04, hp

I have a hp notebook(2015 model) 1.4 Ghz processor  dual core 4gb ram 500 GB hard disk using ubuntu 14.04 and tried running applications like android studio and blender but all don't work well(android studio is slow and at times returns no result in the emulator[google nexus] blender has trouble rendering like objects in motion).what kind of linux os can i use to have the best out of this laptop?

Comment: Exactly what model do you have? What do you mean by "don't work well"? Are they laggy? Have you tried 16.04 or 16.10, like [Murphy suggests](http://askubuntu.com/a/888842/457562)?

Answer (score 3):

Underlying issue here is 1.4 GHz dual core is a pretty slow computer by today's standards.  Lubuntu might help a bit, and if the computer has a GPU, loading the appropriate driver will help some, but the baseline is, you've got a computer with 2006 specs, even though it was made in 2015.  It's not going to do well with high load programs like Blender.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some possibilities for optimization, if the support of 14.04 for your hardware is lacking, but that can't be deduced from your general statement "don't work quite well". And I guess in the end it won't help much. I recommend these two steps:

1. Try the most recent Ubuntu release.
2. If this doesn't help, get a more powerful machine.